# Cannot set notification badge type as number in android 11

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show numbers(notification count) as badges using Firebase messaging, everything is working fine on Android 10 or below, but there is no option to set the notification badge type as a number in the app's "Manage notifications" settings, I can see the option available for Facebook or Whatsapp. Am I missing any permissions or anything in my manifest file or how can I add this option in my app too for Android 11?

| My app's notification settings | Facebook app's notification settings |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |